# Why RestSharp fails in iOS application

Tags: rest, xamarin.ios, restsharp

I'm trying to call REST service using RestSharp library. The code works perfectly fine on Windows environment. However, when I try to execute the code on Mac (for iOS) I get error as

"Error getting response stream (chunked Read1): ReceiveFailure"

The code I'm using is:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://domain.com");
var request = new RestRequest("_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items")
{
RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"domain\username", "password");
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I'm using MacMini with MonoTouch 3.1.1

Comment: 3.1.1 is the MonoDevelop version, not the MonoTouch version. You can get every version numbers from "MonoDevelop" menu, "About MonoDevelop" item, "Version Information" tab. Click on the "Copy Version Information" button and paste this into your question. Please also state if this happens on the simulator, device(s) or both.

Comment: You are using RestSharp compiled for MonoTouch, right? https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/tree/master/RestSharp.MonoTouch

Comment: Hi. I'm using Monotouch: 6.0.10 and RestSharp library. I haven't tried this code on device. But when on emulator, inner exception says 'Connection Reset By Peer'.